# Computing integrals of inverse Fourier transform of function with compact support

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose

$f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support, $f(0) = 1$ and derivatives satisfying $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n = 1,2, \dots$.

Consider
\begin{align*}
K(u) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \infty }^{\infty} e^{i x u} f(x) dx
\end{align*}

Show that
\begin{align*}
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} K(u) du = 1
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} u^j K(u) du = 0 \qquad \forall j = 1,2,\dots
\end{align*}

I know that compact support implies that $f$ vanishes at $\pm \infty$ but I don't see how the other assumptions about $f$ and its derivatives are involved.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Isn't $K(u)$ supposed to be defined as $K(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i x u} \hat{f(x)}$ dx?  You forgot the "hat" symbol over $f$.

Comment: My lecture notes uses this definition and calls it the inverse fourier transform. I'm sure I wrote $K(u)$ correct but I could remove the name 'inverse fourier transform' if its confusing.

Comment: Do you know the Fourier inversion formula? Then note that $u^j \cdot K(u)$ is related to the inverse Fourier transform of $f^{(j)}$ in a simple way.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think I got it, but I didn't use the fact that $f$ has compact support. Is that correct?

Comment: Weaker hypotheses than compact support suffice, but you need that $f$ and all of its derivatives tend to $0$ sufficiently fast as $\lvert x\rvert\to\infty$. Compact support is an easy way to ensure that and make the integration by parts obviously legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fourier inversion formula,

$f(x) = \int_{\infty}^\infty K(u)e^{ixu} du$ so that $1 = f(0) = \int_{\infty}^\infty K(u)$

Moreover, we have that $u^j K(u) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} f^{(j)}(u)$ and the second part of the problem follow from this fact and the restrictions of the derivative of $f$ at zero.

Comment: Does compact support allows us to use the inversion formula, or is that needed for something else?

Comment: Yes.  The fouler inversion formula is first proved for a class of functions known as Schwartz functions and then it is extended by density arguments to a larger class of functions which includes smooth functions with compact support.